# AWS Lambda - how many concurrent HTTP requests can I *send*?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know that Lambda will scale according to incoming requests, but I actually want to write something that functions as something of an amplifier - accepts a request, then broadcasts it out to many external HTTP endpoints.

Are there hard limits of how many HTTP requests I can send out simultaneously? I know normal EC2 boxes have limits, but I'm not sure how Lambda handles it.

Comment: EC2 servers have limits on simultaneous HTTP requests? Where is that documented?

Comment: There is a limit of 1024 file descriptors and also 1024 processes/threads.  So, if you assume each simultaneous HTTP request is a thread that should give you a decent idea, I think.  Of course, you would run out of memory long before then.